# trigger jQuery on load

Tags: jquery, image, background, fade

I would like to have a fade between back ground images on my site. 
I've found out how to trigger a fade with a click but I don't know how I can launch it automatically. I came up with this (JavaScript code):

```
    $('div').click(function (e) {
       $(this).parent().append('<div style="position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 1;" class="google"></div>');
       $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });


function fade() {
        $(this).parent().append('<div style="position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 1;" class="google"></div>');
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
};
```

see at: http://jsfiddle.net/bbqunfhu/1/ the first function is triggered on click and the second one should be called in the "onload" event of the page.
I would like to trigger the fade when the page gets loaded after let's say 10 seconds, I will want to have multiple images it goes through, how can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make correct your jQuery reference/selector in a less relative terms. For example, you can call this in the load instead:

```
function fade() {
        $('div.jquery').parent().append('<div style="position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 1;" class="google"></div>');
        $('div.jquery').fadeOut('slow');
};

fade();
```

[js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnsu5z7y/3/) here.

You original code defined the `fade()` function but didn't call it. That's why the `fade` did not happen. You need to somehow call it.

In addition `$(this).parent()` could mean different things inside `div` is click callback and in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried onReady and setTimeout?

Plain jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(fade, 10000); // this will call fade function 10 sec after page loads.
});
```

Second approach would be to write in your script:

```
 setTimeout(fade, 10000)
```

But include your script with defer atttribute, like so:

Answer (score -1):

As you have right css-classes in place you can do like below
**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/bbqunfhu/6/)**

I've used [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and [fadeComplete](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) handler here.

- We should keep the script in document-ready function handler
- On-Load it'll change the bg-image
- For every click the bg-images will get toggle that are specified in class.

**Script:**

```
$(function () {
    var $div = $('div.jquery').click(function (e) {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('google').fadeIn('slow')
        })
        clearTimeout(clickTimer);
    });
    var clickTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $div.click();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Can I know the down vote cause? What's wrong with this answer?